# Reinforcement learning: enviroment changes a lot while DQN is still computing actions

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn

I'm implementing a agent to dodge skillshots. Here's the problem: while DQN is computing action based on observation, enviroment changed meanwhile. Since those skillshots are quite fast, the enviroment are quite different from observation for DQN. Sometimes when computing finished, my agent has already been hit.[image]

My question is: do I have to do extra work to deal with these changes? Or model itself can adapt to it?

Comment: Welcome to AI Stack Exchange. Is the agent also running DQN training on minibatches, making it slower because it is training its neural network? If yes, then is the delay more acceptable when the agent is _only_ having to calculate its next action and does not need to train?

Comment: @NeilSlater Thanks for your answer. I checked the source code from stable baseline, in which training phase are sepreate from prediction. Besides, prediction only spends around 0.05s and still makes the issue above. I'm quite curious about if there are a topic about this kind of problem.

Comment: The time between the start observation and environment state in your diagrams is 0.05 or less? So the agent has to start moving to avoid being hit in less time than that? Are there prior observations that may give some clue on how the trick short will progress before the fast changing phase?

Comment: usually in training you wait for the env update for the agent to act, however if when deployed you also have this problem, consider developing a lighter NN, or to give a look at Real Time Reinforcement Learning (RTRL)